# Некорректный вывод текста

Tags: php

Здравствуйте!
У меня такая проблема. У меня некорректно выводится информация из базы посредством GET запроса. То есть: я захожу на первую ссылку, текст выводится тот. Захожу на вторую ссылку, показывает то, что показывало в первой ссылке... что не правильного в коде не понимаю.

```
if(@$_GET['id']) {
  $id_cab = (int)$_GET['id'];
    $sql = "SELECT `id`, `title` FROM `subject` WHERE `id`='$id_cab' Limit 1";
     $res = mysql_query($sql);
     $rows = mysql_fetch_array($res);

if($_GET['lecture']) {
$sql = "SELECT * FROM `lesson` WHERE `subject`='$id_cab'";
$res = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
$rows = mysql_fetch_array($res);
echo "<b>$rows[title]</b><p>$rows[lect]";
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Нужно больше кода и структуру бд, связанную с лекцими.

Что делает сейчас ваш код:

```
 - Если переменная $_GET['lecture'] = true, тогда: 1) Запрос в базу 2) Вывод информации
```

Возможно $_GET['lecture'] нужно сравнивать не с true,false а с каким нибудь значением, либо вставить её в запрос тем или иным способом, скажем так:

```
if(!empty($_GET['lecture'])) {
     $lect_id = addslashes($_GET['lecture']);
     $sql = "SELECT * FROM `lesson` WHERE `subject`='$lect_id'";
     $res = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
     $rows = mysql_fetch_array($res);

        echo "<b>$rows[title]</b><p>$rows[lect]";
```

Comment: Подредактировала свой код. Посмотрите.

Comment: Вы получаете переменную $_GET['lecture'] из URI, т.е. примерно так www.сайт.ру/чтото.php?lecture=значение. Так вот переменная приходит верно но в SQL запросе $sql = "SELECT * FROM `lesson` WHERE `subject`='$id_cab'"; никак не участвует, отсюда она (lecture) никак не влияет на выборку данных, уточните в по структуре базы с чем её сравнивать.

Comment: Можете показать на примере что сравнивать?

Comment: Во втором запросе $sql после строчки WHERE нужно сравнить $_GET['lecture'] с чем то, т.е. скажем как я написал в самом первом коде.